# Efficient way for ordering values within group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with time series data, which is packaged in a time long dataframe, something like this:

```
ACCOUNT | VAR1 | VAR2 | DAY
```

I'm interested in creating a new column `DAY_ORD`, which would give the ordinal rank of the `DAY` variable to each row within a group over unique `(ACCOUNT, VAR1, VAR2)` triplets.

Here is a small example of what I want to achieve:

| ACCOUNT | VAR1 | VAR2 | DAY | DAY-ORD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | True | 2022-02-03 | 0 |
| A | X | True | 2022-02-04 | 1 |
| B | X | True | 2021-05-18 | 0 |
| A | X | True | 2022-02-05 | 2 |
| B | X | True | 2022-05-20 | 1 |
| A | Y | True | 2022-02-05 | 0 |
| A | X | True | 2022-03-12 | 3 |

Here is my current implementation:

```
#initialize an empty 'DAY_ORD' column
df['DAY_ORD'] = [None for i in range(len(df))]

#iterate over all triplets that appear in the data
for (_, row) in fb_data[['ACCOUNT', 'VAR1', 'VAR2']].copy().drop_duplicates().iterrows()):
    acc, v1, v2 = row[0], row[1], row[2]

    #find the df slice that adheres to the considered triplet
    fdf = df.loc[(df.ACCOUNT== acc) & (fb_data.VAR1 == v1) & (fb_data.VAR2 == v2)].sort_values('DAY')

    #assign them an ordinal rank
    fdf['DAY_ORD'] = [i for i in range(len(fdf))]

    #set the DAY_ORD values in the original dataframe
    for i in fdf.index:
        df.loc[i, 'DAY_ORD'] = fdf['DAY_ORD'][i]
df['DAY_ORD']
```

It seems like it will do the job, but it runs very slowly, at around `8 it/s`. What is a clean way to make this faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) with convert values to datetimes, subtract `1` and convert to integers:

```
df['DAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DAY'])

df['DAY-ORD'] = (df.groupby(['ACCOUNT', 'VAR1', 'VAR2'])['DAY']
                   .rank('dense').sub(1).astype(int))

print (df)
  ACCOUNT VAR1  VAR2        DAY  DAY-ORD
0       A    X  True 2022-02-03        0
1       A    X  True 2022-02-04        1
2       B    X  True 2021-05-18        0
3       A    X  True 2022-02-05        2
4       B    X  True 2022-05-20        1
5       A    Y  True 2022-02-05        0
6       A    X  True 2022-03-12        3
```

Comment: I'd like to follow this up by only selecting the subset of rows, the groups of which have the maximal day-ord >= 14. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: @VidStropnik - Do you need `df.loc[df['DAY-ORD'].ge(14), ['ACCOUNT', 'VAR1', 'VAR2']]` ?